# Automatically correct umlauts in Chrome like Safari does?

Tags: safari, google-chrome

Safari has one really cool feature.

When type in "Vielen Dank fuer", it automatically corrects it to "Vielen Dank für".

Can Chrome do the same? If so, anyone knows how?